# How to fix width and height of plot in figure in python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have a question, I am plotting in python and I put these plots together in Latex. The figure sizes are the same, however, as you can see the plot width and height of the axes of the plot are not the same. Also because figure a has one xlabel (alive or dead), while figure b has two (the numbers range and 'amount of days'.

[image]

Anyone has an idea how I can set the width and height of the plot?
I already tried `put.figure(figsize(x,y)` but that only fixes the figure length, but I need to fix the size within the figure.

Thanks

Comment: Am I right in thinking you want to make the box that makes up the actual plots the same size? You can probably achieve that if you play around with `plt.figure(figsize=(x, y))`. You will be able to change the length and width, not just the length. You could also try plotting them as subplots. `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(x, y))`